# How to sync an animation with a sound bpm

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've a 145 BPM sound with 137 milliseconds offset and I'm trying to sync a really fast animation with it... I was trying this way:

```
public class ActiveEpilepsy : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Epilepsy; //GameObject that carries the animation
    float delay = 0.2f; //a fair time to disable the Epilepsy after the animation runs before active again

    void Start()
    {       
        InvokeRepeating("activeEpilepsy", 0.137f, 2.416f);  //second parameter is the offset of the music and the third is the bpm/60;
    }

    void activeEpilepsy()
    {
         while(delay >= 0)
         {
            Epilepsy.SetActive(true);
            delay -= Time.deltaTime;
         }

         Epilepsy.SetActive(false);

    }
}
```

but doesn't activate the GameObject at all and returns A BEAUTIFUL CRASH in my Unity... Also, people tell that I shouldn't use strings to call methods (Invoke example), so what is wrong with my code and how can I make this works without using an Invoke?

Answer (score 1):

Problem happens here:

```
void activeEpilepsy()
{
     while(delay <= 0)
     {
        Epilepsy.SetActive(true);
        delay -= Time.deltaTime;
     }

     Epilepsy.SetActive(false);

}
```

You have a while loop that will run as long as delay is less than 0. And you are decreasing that value inside. So either, delay is more than 0 and the loop does not enter. Or it is lower or equal to 0 and it will never leave.

Since delay is 0.2f, the loop is useless and the object deactivates right away. You need a coroutine or another invoke there:

```
void activeEpilepsy()
{
     Epilepsy.SetActive(true);
     Invoke("Reset", this.delay);
}
void Reset(){Epilepsy.SetActive(false);}
```

That is it for the inactive object problem. The crash is probably elsewhere, I can't see anything running wrong here.

For the method as string, it's not about calling with string, it's about how it is handled. I think (to be confirmed) Invoke uses reflection, so it calls on the assembly manifest to figure out if the method exists. This would be slow. If Unity was smart enough to add the method to a dictionary then calling by string has little to no impact.

Comment: Yep, I saw the "<=" after posting it, but I fixed in my code and stills not running as the expected... :/

Comment: With the edit, you need to reset delay after each usage.